# What does torchvision.transforms.Resize(size, interpolation=2) actually do?

Tags: deep-learning, resize, pytorch, torch

Does it add to the image if too small or crop if too big or just stretch the image to the desired size?

Comment: What is missing in the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Resize) in your opinion?

Comment: Could you please update your question a and provide a description?

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough, I'm just unsure about whether resize stretches the image to the desired size or adds/removes pixels from the original image. I wasn't asking about interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

When you set interpolation=2, then you are using Bilinear interpolation, ti can be either used for upsampling or down sampling. In the case of upsampling you are doing something like [image]

There are several types of upsampling and down-sampling, but bilinear one uses a combination of the neighbouring pixels to cimpute the new pixel.

Look to this links for more informations: [link1](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/releasenotes/2.7.0.html); [link2](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/38118/what-is-the-difference-between-upsampling-and-bi-linear-upsampling-in-a-cnn)

Answer (score 0):

Resize stretches the image to span the new size. It samples from the original image using the provided interpolation method.